# Can I Pipe Powershell output to an accelerator?

Tags: powershell, type-accelerators

I've obtained a file path to an xml-resource, by interrogating task scheduler arguments.
I'd like to pipe these files paths to [xml], to return data using XPath.

Online I see accelerators and variables are used, eg

```
$xml = [XML](Get-Content .\Test.xml)
```

tried piping to convert-to-xml, but that's an XML object containing the filepath, so I need to convert to [xml] - hoping to do this in the pipeline, potentially for > 1 xmldocument

Is it possible to *pipe to* [typeaccelerators] ?
Should I be piping to New-Object, or Tee-Variable, as required?

I hope to eventually be able to construct a one-liner to interrogate several nodes (eg LastRan, LastResult)

currently I have this, which only works for one

```
([xml](Get-Content ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath *mytask* | select -First 1).Actions.Arguments | % {$_.Split('"')[-2]}))).MyDocument.LastRan
```

returns the value of LastRan, from MyDocument node.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For me it's not clear what you are asking, perhaps you can give a XML file sample and explain what you are waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take pipeline input you need to make a function and set the parameter attribute `ValueFromPipeline`

```
Function Convert-XML {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$xml
    )

    process{
        [xml]$xml
    }
}
```

Then you could take the content of an xml file (all at once, not line by line)

```
Get-Content .\Test.xml -Raw | Convert-XML
```

Of course to get your one liner you'd probably want to add the logic for that in the function. However this is how you'd handle pipeline input.

Comment: But keep in mind ... this will not combine your XMLs at root node.. You only get a collection of XML objects. And "ConvertFrom-Xml" would be better.